# How to resolve Not unique table/alias error in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, laravel-relations, laravel-models

I am very new to the laravel,i am using l5-repository package for orderBy and sortedBy to sort columns ,while hitting API i am getting following error please help me to resolve the issue

my API URL :-http://localhost.com/v1/domain?limit=250&page=1&orderBy=users|name&sortedBy=desc

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You probrably have an error in your table name. For default, laravel will look for `cards` table name for a model named `Card`. Also, take a look in your models name. I espect you misstype `card.php` because it should be `Card.php`. Laravel uses a lot of psr convention and Eloquent (who deal with relationships and that stuff). If you are not well versed into it, take a look in how to name classes. As Alireza said, take a look in the Laravel's documentation, it is awesome and complete. When you have a one to many realtionship, one of they should have a `hasMany(...)` instead `belongsTo(....)`

Comment: my model name is Card.php only

Comment: These changes I had propoused solved your problem? If not, plz let me know.